# Can't delete first value of my array

Tags: php, arrays

I got a script that shows products according to their id. In the echoed data there is a link which redirects the user to the same page but with a posted id, according to that id I delete a product (id) from my session which is an array. This works perfectly except for the first array value. What could be causing that?

How I have my code at the moment:

```
//Link to quote page and send product id with it

echo '<p><a class="offertelink" href="offerte.php?product='.$productcr[0]['id'].'">Request a quote</a></p>';
```

On my quote page:

```
ob_start();
include 'includes/header.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'] = array();
}

// Check if product is set before putting it in an array
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !in_array($_GET['product'], $_SESSION['product'])){
    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
}

// Implode array to use ids in query
$prods  = implode(",", $_SESSION['product']);
```

Query:

```
if(count($_SESSION['product'])  != 0){
//  Get all products with id in session
$offerte            = "SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE `id` in (".$conn->real_escape_string($prods).")  AND state = 1";
$offertecon         = $conn->query($offerte);
$offertecr          = array();
while ($offertecr[] = $offertecon->fetch_array());
}
```

And finally below my query:

```
// Check if id is send, and delete from session accordingly
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $productID  = $_GET['id'];
    if( $index = array_search($productID, $_SESSION['product']) ) {
        $_SESSION['product'][$index] = null;
        unset($_SESSION['product'][$index]);
        header('Location: http://www.web.nl/_extern/web/offerte.php');
    } 
}

if(count($_SESSION['product']) == 0){
    echo 'No products added';
}else{
    foreach($offertecr as $product){

        $offerte_imgs = $product['images']; // Get image parameters of the article
        $offertepic = json_decode($offerte_imgs); // Split the parameters apart

        if($offertepic->{'image_intro'} != ''){
            $image = 'cms/'.$offertepic->{'image_intro'};
        }else{
            $image = 'http://www.web.nl/_extern/web/cms/images/Producten/Untitled-7.jpg';
        }

        if($product['id'] != ''){
            if (strlen($product['introtext']) > 100){
                $shortcat = substr($product['introtext'], 0, 100) . '...';
            }else{
                $shortcat = $product['introtext'];
            }
            $deleteLink        = "offerte.php?id=".$product['id'];
            $offerteoverzicht .= '
            <div class="row productofferte">
                <a href="producten/'.$product['alias'].'.html">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offerteimg">
                            <img style="border:1px solid #ddd;" src="'.$image.'">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="desc">
                    <a style="color:#2d4160;" href="producten/'.$product['alias'].'.html"><p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$product['title'].' </a>
                        <a href="'.$deleteLink.'">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p>'.$shortcat.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
    }
}

echo $offerteoverzicht;
```

I've read a bit on my problem and figured it has something to do with shifting the array if I'm correct. If I print my session all the arrays are deleted from it, except the first one. Doesn't matter what id it is, when I change the first product then that product cannot be deleted from the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test on finding an element in an array with [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) should compare to `false`. Doing `!` will return `false` when the element found is at index 0:

Change:

```
if( $index = array_search($productID, $_SESSION['product']) ) {
```

to:

```
if( ($index = array_search($productID, $_SESSION['product'])) !== false ) {
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes.